# I get this error: "glibc detected"

Tags: c++, memory, vector, g++, glibc

I just wrote a piece of CPP code and I compiled it using G++ in ubuntu.
When I run my code everything is fine, the code runs well and gives output but doesn't exit and it gives this error:

```
 *** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x09f931f0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x6c501)[0x3de501]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x6dd70)[0x3dfd70]
/lib/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6d)[0x3e2e5d]
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdlPv+0x21)[0x6e2441]
./a.out[0x8049ce6]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x2f69e)[0x3a169e]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x2f70f)[0x3a170f]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xef)[0x388cef]
./a.out[0x8048a61]
======= Memory map: ========
00219000-0021a000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
00354000-00370000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8781845    /lib/ld-2.12.1.so
00370000-00371000 r--p 0001b000 08:01 8781845    /lib/ld-2.12.1.so
00371000-00372000 rw-p 0001c000 08:01 8781845    /lib/ld-2.12.1.so
00372000-004c9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8781869    /lib/libc-2.12.1.so
004c9000-004ca000 ---p 00157000 08:01 8781869    /lib/libc-2.12.1.so
004ca000-004cc000 r--p 00157000 08:01 8781869    /lib/libc-2.12.1.so
004cc000-004cd000 rw-p 00159000 08:01 8781869    /lib/libc-2.12.1.so
004cd000-004d0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00638000-00717000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3935829    /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
00717000-0071b000 r--p 000de000 08:01 3935829    /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
0071b000-0071c000 rw-p 000e2000 08:01 3935829    /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
0071c000-00723000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00909000-0092d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8781918    /lib/libm-2.12.1.so
0092d000-0092e000 r--p 00023000 08:01 8781918    /lib/libm-2.12.1.so
0092e000-0092f000 rw-p 00024000 08:01 8781918    /lib/libm-2.12.1.so
00fdb000-00ff5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8781903    /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
00ff5000-00ff6000 r--p 00019000 08:01 8781903    /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
00ff6000-00ff7000 rw-p 0001a000 08:01 8781903    /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
08048000-0804b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8652645    /home/akg/Desktop/contest/a.out
0804b000-0804c000 r--p 00002000 08:01 8652645    /home/akg/Desktop/contest/a.out
0804c000-0804d000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 8652645    /home/akg/Desktop/contest/a.out
09f93000-09fb4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7600000-b7621000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7621000-b7700000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7765000-b7768000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7775000-b7779000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
bf9a7000-bf9c8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Aborted
```

What does this mean? How can i get rid of it?
I'm not using malloc or free , I'm just using vector!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Even if you're not allocating memory directly, it happens under the hood in `vector` code and you most likely corrupted some portion of memory by writing where you are not supposed to. The most likely reasons I can think of are:

1. Writing to an element that is out of bounds
2. Using a pointer/reference to an element that is no longer valid -- note that inserting more elements can invalidate earlier references

Of course, I can't say for sure unless you post some relevant code. Or try using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) to find the source of the problem.

Answer (score 6):

This means you called `free` on a non valid pointer (ie: a pointer not allocated via malloc, or that you already freed).

Paste some code, else it's impossible to say why this happens.

Comment: It can also mean that malloc heap management data has been corrupted