# what does this error mean in C: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00000000020b0200

Tags: c, scope, free

I use a for-loop to create objects of my customized data structure, and perform some manipulations on them. The objects contain `ucontext_t` fields, so I am basically doing `makecontext` and `swapcontext`. The stack size assignment for each `ucontext_t` object is the default `SIGSTKSZ`.

After compiling my programs with `gcc`, and the running results contain the following errors underneath. Does this error mean that my memory was not freed before exiting from my program? In general, what can you tell from this error?

```
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00000000020b0200 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7eb96)[0x7ffeb31acb96]
./a.out[0x401261]
./a.out[0x4009fe]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x364a0)[0x7ffeb31644a0]
./a.out[0x401080]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7ffeb314f76d]
./a.out[0x400899]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 23921                              /home/cs/Development/C/gtthreads_fresh/a.out
00601000-00602000 r--p 00001000 08:01 23921                              /home/cs/Development/C/gtthreads_fresh/a.out
00602000-00603000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 23921                              /home/cs/Development/C/gtthreads_fresh/a.out
020a2000-020c5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7ffeb2f18000-7ffeb2f2d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 136328                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffeb2f2d000-7ffeb312c000 ---p 00015000 08:01 136328                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffeb312c000-7ffeb312d000 r--p 00014000 08:01 136328                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffeb312d000-7ffeb312e000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 136328                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffeb312e000-7ffeb32e3000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 136874                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7ffeb32e3000-7ffeb34e3000 ---p 001b5000 08:01 136874                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7ffeb34e3000-7ffeb34e7000 r--p 001b5000 08:01 136874                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7ffeb34e7000-7ffeb34e9000 rw-p 001b9000 08:01 136874                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7ffeb34e9000-7ffeb34ee000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffeb34ee000-7ffeb3510000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 137879                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7ffeb36f9000-7ffeb36fc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffeb370c000-7ffeb3710000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffeb3710000-7ffeb3711000 r--p 00022000 08:01 137879                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7ffeb3711000-7ffeb3713000 rw-p 00023000 08:01 137879                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7fff659db000-7fff659fc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff659fe000-7fff65a00000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Usually it means the buffer passed to `free` was overflowed before the  call to `free`.

Comment: This question has already been answered here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899582/i-get-this-error-glibc-detected

Comment: It means you've invoked undefined behavior by overwriting *something*, *somewhere.* And since you asked, one thing I can tell from this map is your not compiling with debugging symbols enabled (`-g`). **Valgrind** is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

This means either you are freeing an invalid address or more likely have overwritten the bounds of an allocated block. @Cantfindmyname gave you [I get this error: "glibc detected"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899582/i-get-this-error-glibc-detected) which tells you what the problem is, but not how to find out where your program is causing the problem, as these things are difficult to find. The best tool here is `valgrind` which will (normally) pretty quickly find anything naughty you are doing with memory, especially heap memory.